# Datagridview - condition within condition

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagridview, conditional-statements

I think I'll explain this best with an image.

[image]

I am using this line of code for datagridview above :

```
        Dim SQLString As String = "SELECT NALOG, KONTO, DATPRO, BRDOK, OPIS, DUGUJE, POTRAZUJE FROM PROMGL WHERE NALOG LIKE '%U-%' AND DATPRO between #1/1/2014# and #12/31/2014#"
```

What I would like to do is only to take NALOG U-0004 and U-0005 in datagridview because they have "2702" in KONTO, since NALOG U-0001, U-0002 and U-0003 don't have "2702" I would like for them to be ignored.

If I add `WHERE KONTO LIKE %2702%` I'll get only 2702 items in datagridview and other parts of NALOG that contains 2702 will be ignored and I would like to populate datagridview with complete NALOG if in KONTO is item 2702.

Is is possible to insert that condition within this condition `WHERE NALOG LIKE '%U-%'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a subquery to do that.

```
SELECT * From yourTable WHERE Nalog IN 
  (SELECT Nalog FROM yourTable 
  WHERE NALOG LIKE '%U-%' 
  AND DATPRO between #1/1/2014# and #12/31/2014# 
  AND KONTO LIKE '%2702%')
```